# Tomcat7 loops requests in ubuntu with spring. How to fix?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ubuntu, spring-security

I have two OS. Windows and Ubuntu 14. In windows all ok: Spring, Spring Security and etc, but i need to use Ubuntu. In ubuntu every 600 ms smth send request to my tomcat server, and i don't know who. This is log:

```
02:26:08.327 [http-bio-9821-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [isAuthenticated()]
02:26:08.327 [http-bio-9821-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
02:26:08.327 [http-bio-9821-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@626a603b, returned: -1
02:26:08.327 [http-bio-9821-exec-4] WARN  o.s.c.s.ResourceBundleMessageSource - ResourceBundle [messages/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages/messages, locale ru_RU
02:26:08.328 [http-bio-9821-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_76]
02:26:08.328 [http-bio-9821-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:9821/]
02:26:08.328 [http-bio-9821-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Calling Authentication entry point.
02:26:08.329 [http-bio-9821-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'http://localhost:9821/login;jsessionid=9566026EBB200B1A17B02F5DB6C05687'
02:26:08.329 [http-bio-9821-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
02:26:08.329 [http-bio-9821-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@47fa58f3. A new one will be created.
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest - queryString: both null (property equals)
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest - requestURI: arg1=/; arg2=/login;jsessionid=9566026EBB200B1A17B02F5DB6C05687 (property not equals)
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - saved request doesn't match
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 9566026EBB200B1A17B02F5DB6C05687; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login; Attributes: [permitAll()]
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 9566026EBB200B1A17B02F5DB6C05687; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@626a603b, returned: 1
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
02:26:08.332 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
02:26:08.333 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'airport' processing HEAD request for [/login;jsessionid=9566026EBB200B1A17B02F5DB6C05687]
02:26:08.333 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /login
02:26:08.333 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'HEAD' not supported
02:26:08.333 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'HEAD' not supported
02:26:08.333 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'HEAD' not supported
02:26:08.333 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'HEAD' not supported
02:26:08.333 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
02:26:08.334 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'airport': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
02:26:08.334 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
02:26:08.334 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
02:26:08.334 [http-bio-9821-exec-8] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - / at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/login'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/'
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [isAuthenticated()]
02:26:08.338 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
02:26:08.339 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@626a603b, returned: -1
02:26:08.339 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] WARN  o.s.c.s.ResourceBundleMessageSource - ResourceBundle [messages/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages/messages, locale ru_RU
02:26:08.340 [http-bio-9821-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.52.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_76]
```

//etc...

I changed port of my tomcat server, check if not having any spring-security loops: `<security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()"/>`. But it's necessary, because from browser all works good, but my log file scary me. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at the access log? Are you running apache or some kind of load balancer which might be checking if the tomcat service is still alive?

Comment: No, i have not any load balancer. At runtime of tomcat i also have running phpmyadmin and mysql. That's all. Also this tools i run at windows. Now, i got OutOfMemory :(

Comment: @Jason i also change port of tomcat to 9821, before i use 8080, 4567, etc... I think, if this "spam" app will not know port of tomcat, it can't send requests. I note that this spam request try get access to "/", but i have ROLE_ANONYMOOS only to /login, /logout.

Answer (score 0):

I had very strange answer. In development i use IntelliJ IDEA. In my Tomcat Configuration Server(in IDEA) for deploy there is radio button "After launch :" and set of browsers. In my case radio button was set on and browser was "Default". So IDEA can't choose default(or maybe anything else) browser and go into infinity loop.

Comment: so after you choose the browser, there is no periodical request in your log?

Comment: @HoàngLong yes, i dont have anymore requests,but i disable button.